# (48) wrong parameters: MOV CX,DATO (48) operands do not match: 16 bit register and 8 bit address

Tags: assembly, x86

(50) wrong parameters: MOV  CX,DATO
(50) operands do not match: 16 bit register and 8 bit address

this the code

```
    DATO DB ?,'$'
    DATO1 DB ?,'$'

    .CODE
    MAIN PROC
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX

START:

    LEA DX,CAD
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H

CALCULO:
    LEA DX,CAD1
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H
    MOV DATO,AL
    ADD AL,30

    CMP AL,'0'
    JNGE MENSAJE
    CMP AL,'9'
    JNG MENSAJE
    CMP AL,'A'
    JNGE CONTINUE
    CMP AL,'Z'
    JNG CONTINUE

 MENSAJE:
    LEA DX,CAD3
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    JMP CALCULO 



 CONTINUE:
    LOOP:
    MOV CX,DATO
    ADD DATO,DATO
    DEC CX
    JNZ LOOP
```

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear to you? `CX` is a 16bit register, `DATO` is defined as 8bit values. Also please edit the question and format the code properly

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory: the sizes of the operands in the instruction `mov cx, DATO` do not match. `CX` is a 16-bit register, whereas you defined `DATO` as an 8-bit value (using the `DB` directive—*d*eclare *b*yte).

Also, I guess you're probably assembling this code using something like MASM or TASM that is extremely forgiving with the syntax allowed to dereference memory. Since you want to move the *value* of `DATO`, rather than the address, you *should* have put it in brackets. The correct way to write the instruction would have been:

```
mov  cx, BYTE PTR [DATO]
```

…and then the problem would have been obvious.

One way you could fix this would be to move `DATO` into an 8-bit register:

```
mov  cl, BYTE PTR [DATO]
```

You will then need to adjust the surrounding code so that it uses the `CL` register. In particular, you should `dec cl`.

Or, if you're targeting the 386 or later, you could do a move with zero-extension:

```
movzx cx, BYTE PTR [DATO]
```

Then, you don't need to modify your code at all.

---

You will immediately have another problem, though. This instruction:

```
ADD DATO,DATO
```

is impossible. You cannot have two memory operands in a single instruction. You need to use a register as an intermediate. So the code will need to look something like:

```
Loop:
    mov  cl, BYTE PTR [DATO]
    mov  al, cl
    add  al, al
    mov  BYTE PTR [DATO], al
    dec  cl
    jnz  Loop
```

Notice that this clobbers the AL`(or`AX`) register. If you need to preserve that value, you could use a different register as the "scratch" register.

Finally, ask yourself what will happen when `cl` is zero. The `jnz` branch won't be taken, and so execution will fall through to…what? Oops.

Comment: "Notice that this clobbers the `AL` register" Would it be much worse to use the Read-Modify-Write version `mov cl, byte ptr [DATO]` `add byte ptr [DATO], cl` ? And what about `shl byte ptr [DATO], 1` ?

Comment: @Sep Both of those are perfectly valid ways to write the code. There's always multiple ways to do something in assembly! On semi-modern processors (i.e., Pentium and later), you will probably get better performance by avoiding the RMW instructions, especially because it allows you flexibility in cleverly ordering (scheduling) the instructions (which I didn't do here to keep things simple). But the difference won't be significant enough to matter in 99% of cases.